# Java bin file won't install manually

Tags: installation, java, binary

I downloaded a java bin file manually from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html). Then I tried to install it using the following commands. But I am not able to install it. Can anybody help me to install manually?

```
aneal@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sh jdk-6u25-linux-i586.bin
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
Extracting...
jdk-6u25-linux-i586.bin: 113: ./install.sfx.5171: not found
Failed to extract the files.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of
the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information.


aneal@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo ./jdk-6u25-linux-i586.bin
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
Extracting...
./jdk-6u25-linux-i586.bin: 113: ./install.sfx.5197: not found
Failed to extract the files.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of
the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information.
```

PS : My architecture is x86

Comment: The installation file is for the x86 architecture - is your Ubuntu's architecture version also x86?

Comment: Can you add the output of "uname -a"

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 4):

First, re-double-check that you are installing 32-bit Java on a 32-bit OS (or installing 64-bit Java on a 64-bit OS). While it's possible to install 32-bit Java on 64-bit Linux, usually there's no reason to (and you need to install extra dependencies to do it).

Second, clean up the old extracted files if the first installation attempt fails. Yo shouldn't have to "sudo" to install.

Third, don't try to "sh" the installer; instead, just make it executable (therefore you aren't relying on finding the right "sh" in your PATH):

```
$ chmod a+x ./jdk-6u25-linux-i586.bin
$ ./jdk-6u25-linux-i586.bin
```

Lastly, although you want to manually install the jdk.bin, you can first try to install the packaged JDK, to make sure you have all the dependencies.  Depending on your version of Ubuntu, you might just be able to:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

You might have to add a ppa repository (pre-10.04) or enable "partner" repositories (10.04/10.10 or later).  This has changed a bit from version to version (of ubuntu). (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747789/how-to-install-sun-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat )

Comment: tried already ! no luck !!

Comment: maybe try a different version of Java and see if you get the same error, or at least more info on what the problem might be. Try java5, or java7 - see this question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/32124/how-do-i-install-java-7-from-the-official-tarballs ...  But if the "apt-get install sun-java6-jdk" worked, then consider it "job done"; there's no need to install the ".bin" manually anymore. If you want more than one jdk, just apt-get alternatives / galternatives.